# Determine the number of datapoints that meet a criteria

Tags: r

How can I find out the number of datapoints that I have in a data frame, that meet a specific criteria?

```
Group<-c("Group 1","Group 1","Group 1","Group 2","Group 2")
Factor<-c("Factor 1", "Factor 1", "Factor 2", "Factor 1", "Factor 2")

data<-data.frame(cbind(Group,Factor))
data
```

For instance, I would like to know how many data points are in Group 1, Factor 2. 
I think I should be able to use the `summary` function, but I can't figure out how do specify that I want combinations of the factor levels. For instance:

```
summary(data) #Verifies that Group 1 appears 3 times, and Factor 2 appears twice, but no information on how many times Group 1 AND Factor 2 appear in the same row
```

So, how do I get the summary table of *combinations* of different factor levels?

Comment: This is separate to the answer, but you don't need `cbind` in there `data <- data.frame(Group,Factor)` would work. It's also generally not a good idea to call your datasets `data` as it conflicts with the `data()` function.

Comment: FYI: Please note [criterion](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/criterion) is the singular of criteria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a logical test and then `sum` for a specific combination:

```
sum(with(data,Group=="Group 1" & Factor=="Factor 2"))
[1] 1
```

To extend this, you could simply use `table`:

```
with(data,table(Group,Factor))

         Factor
Group     Factor 1 Factor 2
  Group 1        2        1
  Group 2        1        1
```

...which if you convert back to a `data.frame` gives a nice little summary dataset:

```
data.frame(with(data,table(Group,Factor)))

    Group   Factor Freq
1 Group 1 Factor 1    2
2 Group 2 Factor 1    1
3 Group 1 Factor 2    1
4 Group 2 Factor 2    1
```

Comment: Agree that `table` is the answer and `as.data.frame.table` is very useful. And  `with(data, table(interaction(Group,Factor)))` if you don't want a rectangular display. Also `tapply(something, list(fac1,fac2,fac3), length)`.

Comment: @DWIN, the `list()` within the `tapply()` was something I was also trying to do. I had tried using `c(fac1,fac2)` in the function, but it didn't work.